# Featured site from hot questions page shows 0 questions 0 answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, featured-site

When browsing the hot questions page (or just the front page really: https://stackexchange.com/?page=1) in the top right it shows today's featured site. However it shows 0 questions and 0 answers for the Methematica Stack even though the site has plenty when I navigate to it.

What I see is shown in the result below, and persists through refreshes. I believe this is a bug unless this is some mathematics joke I'm not getting.

[image: Image that shows 0 questions 0 answers]

Comment: Nah, no joke. Something moved, breaking something nobody tested or saw. It's pretty common when making changes behind the scenes, and these days with the move to new server side framework (.NET Core) tons of such changes are made.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just kicked the caches, should be up and running again

Comment: It [keeps happening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331600/bug-displaying-statistics-of-featured-site). While nothing fatal, any chance to take a look at the source of the bug and fix it? :)