# Bug displaying statistics of featured site

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, featured-site

#### 0 questions, 0 answers, NaN% answered?

[image]

Comment: Same bug as [a couple months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328282/398063), caching thing to kick up, apparently.

Comment: This is a status-completed NaN [bug report from long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136304/282094). Without a recent update here, this is assumed no-repro.